# Where is documentation explaining how tag wikis get edited/reviewed?

Tags: discussion

I've edited the arcobjects tag wiki, https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/arcobjects/info

It says it will be only visible to me until it has been peer reviewed.  Don't my peers need to see it in order to review it?

Can any of you see my edits?

Is there any documentation on this?

Answer (score 5):

You can [review and approve edits at 5K rep](https://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) and [make them at 20K](https://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user), I recall.  For details, click on your current rep (shown at the top), choose the "privileges" link from the pop-up, then hyperlink to any privilege listed on the right.

However, the "tools" menu that was available in beta has vanished: it was through this that we were made aware of pending edits to review, etc.  I haven't found any way to become aware of tag wiki edits automatically.  If I suspect one has been made I can get to it through the tag:

- Find the 'arcobjects' tag.
- Link through 'edit'.
- Link through 'edit pending'.
- Vote.  (I just approved it.)

Thus, it seems that in effect the only "peers" currently present on this site are the mods.

Comment: Thanks, I just was notified that I've earned the "tag editor" badge!  There's been [mention](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69049/would-it-be-useful-to-be-able-to-vote-for-canonical-answers) of "canonical answers".  I think this is a good concept, but I don't see anything that flags an answer as being canonical.  Maybe canonization could be handled through the tag wiki editing process, simply by maintaining a list of links to canonical answers.

Comment: I just created a "contour" tag and a wiki for it.  Any takers?

Comment: Just approved it.